# SQL WHERE and AND clause

Tags: sql

When we do a query such as this

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM A, B, C
WHERE A.type = B.type
AND B.cost = C.cost
```

What can we say about the result table? What will the size of the result table be?
If A has 5 rows, B has 8 rows, and C has 7 rows

EDIT: Can I please get some response instead of mark down? I am total new to SQL and need help.

EDIT2: **What I am trying to do -** Understand how WHERE and AND clause works & why the result table has 8 rows

**How you came to this particular question -**  I was reading my textbook and doing the questions in it

**What I've tried to solve it -** I tried Google and reading various of posts but most of them just shows HOW to do it instead of explaining what's actually happpening

Comment: I thought WHERE and AND will work?

Comment: This might be a better question if you tell us what you're trying to do, how you came to this particular question, and what you've tried to solve it.  (As a better question, it would generate better answers.)

Comment: @bdares, took your advice. Thanks

Comment: @Dino55, you cannot say that the result will always be 8. It depends on the common elements present. Show us the sample input.

Comment: @NiladriBiswas - that's the part I am confused about. Why is it 8. This example is in the textbook and is based on a Database that the author provided. I don't know how I can type it all..

Comment: @Dino55 , You r actually doing a cross join SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A, B, C where the result will be 5*8*7 = 280 and then performing a filter condition to get the matching items.

Comment: @Dyno55 I don't think I follow your 5*8*7 logic: if you `select count(*)` you will always get exactly 1 column in the output and exactly 1 row in the output (unless `group by` is used, which in this case is not). So in the OP's original question, the answer is: 1 row with 1 column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The count will be the number of  common values . E.g. Consider this small example

```
DECLARE @A Table(Val1 Int)
Insert Into @A Values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)


DECLARE @B Table(Val2 Int)
Insert Into @B Values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)


DECLARE @C Table(Val3 Int)
Insert Into @C Values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7)


SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM @A a, @B b, @C c
WHERE a.Val1 = b.Val2
AND b.Val2 = c.Val3
```

The result is **5**. Because `a.Val1 = b.Val2` has 5 common elements viz 1,2 3,4,5. Now `b.Val2 = c.Val3` has 6 common elements viz 1,2,3,4,5,6.

Then these two result sets will act upon each other and will try to get the intersecting values i.e. common values which is again 1,2,3,4,5. Hence is the count as 5

Comment: Your answers is amazing :) I totally understand now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The size of the result set depends on, unsurprisingly, the number of 3-tuples of A, B, and C entities that match the `WHERE` conditions.

Now, this completely depends on the data.  You could have a set of data where A.type is all `Apples`, and B.type is all `Oranges`, and your conditions are never satisfied, so your result set is empty.

On the other extreme, the types for all rows match, so you end up with every single possible combination, or 5*8*7 result rows.